# Does a mean value theorem hold in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Assume you have a function $f(x,y)$ such that $x$ and $y$ can take values on $[0,T]$ but we have to have that $y \ge x$. Assume also that $f(x,x)=0$. For each $x$ we have that

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x,x+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}=g(x),$$ and that $g$ is continuous.

Do we then have for each $x\in [0,T)$ and each $\Delta t$ such that $x+\Delta t\le T$ that
$$\frac{f(x,x+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}=g(c),$$ for some $c \in (x,x+\Delta t)$?

If it helps, we can also assume that for a given $x$, $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$, and for a given $y$, f(x,y) is continuous in $x$. But I'd rather not use these assumptions if not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whetter $f(x,y)$ is continuons or not, the mean value theorem as you stated doesn't hold.

Consider $f(x,y)=(y-x)^2$, then
$$\lim_{\Delta t\to0^+}\frac{f(x,x+\Delta t)-f(x,x)}{\Delta t}=\lim_{\Delta t\to0^+}\frac{\Delta t^2}{\Delta t}=0$$
Hence $g(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Finally,
$$\frac{f(x,x+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}={\Delta t}\neq0$$